# how to pass a complete object or wrapper class as parameter in lightning component after enabling locker service?

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning, napili

I am using custom lightning components in my napili community, we use to call @AuraEnabled methods on save which will perform desired operation.
In this calling we were able to pass a variable of standard/custom object types or wrapper class type

But after enabling "Locker Service" criticle update we are not able to pass object type variable as parameter, we are not even abale to send it after converting into JSON.

The only workaround which worked for me is passing each and every fields as parameters and assemble them again in apex method.
But this is also having issue if we have lots of fields on UI to send in Save method because we can't pass more then 32 parameters.

Any suggestion or workaround ?

Comment: what behaviour(i.e error message) you are seeing? please share the code snippet?

Comment: are you able to pass List<Sobject> ? If yes, then you can pass wrapper list also.

Comment: Any chance you could post your JSON encode / decode source? I do the same thing and have had no problems so far (and I have Locker (dis?)Service enabled)

Comment: Hi all thanks for your responses, actually the issue was because of some other custom component I have used in same component, which did not allowed me to pass the object. When  removed it that worked fine.  Thanks for all Suggestions!